# my facebook-addicted friend is ghosting me

Tags: friends

How do I ask my friend to respond to my Facebook message without coming off as needy when I know that he is constantly logging on and off FB and is not at work?

Comment: You might like to check out these somewhat related questions: [1](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/583/how-to-determine-if-someone-is-deliberately-ignoring-my-messages), [2](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/2211/message-being-seen-but-not-responded-what-is-the-correct-response)

Answer (score 7):

Simple : you don’t.

The best way to react to someone who’s ghosting you is to stop messaging him.

Firstly, you should respect the fact that maybe he doesn’t want to talk to you / talk to anyone.

Secondly, the less you talk to him, the more he’ll feel your absence and want to talk to you.